# Search for multiple strings at once

Tags: c++, search, vector, find

I want to search for multiple strings in a vector at once.

i.e vector = "H" "H" "I" "I"
    vector2 = "H" "I"

so i want to search vector with the contents of vector2 my code is below but i don't think it is the best way. If all the strings are present then return a identifier so i know all strings are present.

could someone check the code below just to see if its correct :) Thanks

```
std::vector<std::string> test; 
        test.push_back("YES");
        test.push_back("YES");
        test.push_back("NO");
        test.push_back("NO");

        std::vector<std::string> test1; 
        test1.push_back("YES");
        test1.push_back("NO");

        std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
        for(int i = 0; i < test1.size(); i++)
        {



            if(find (test.begin(), test.end(),test[i]) != test.begin() )
            {
                DCS_LOG_DEBUG("Some elements have appeared more than once...");

            }

        }
```

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison is incorrect. If you want to check if there **is at least one** element in the container instead of:

```
if(find(test.begin(), test.end(),test[i]) != test.begin())
```

you should use:

```
if(find(test.begin(), test.end(),test1[i]) != test.end())
```

[because `find` returns `test.end()`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find.html) when it founds no match.

If you want to **check if more than one element** exists use [`count`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/count.html):

```
if(count(test.begin(), test.end(),test1[i]) > 1)
```

Comment: no i do not need to check if more than on element exists just need to find out if there both there and if not exit the loop and signal a error @RafalRawicki

Comment: I guess i could retrieve the count for each and check if they are equal to one  @RafalRawicki

Comment: The log message "Some elements have appeared more than once..." was unclear to me. Anyway, comparing to `test.begin()` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Log message is jsut saying that there are some elements which should not have appeared more than once

Comment: i am using that if `count` now however when i put an `else` it will execute both, hmm but i do not need a `else` here i can just `break` in the if but just saying

Answer (score 1):

A problem could be:

```
if(find (test.begin(), test.end(),test[i]) != test.begin() )
```

instead of

```
if(find (test.begin(), test.end(),test1[i]) != test.end() )
```

Your version looks for elements of `test` inside of `test`, which will always return a valid iterator.

Other than that, when you find a `string` that is not present, you can just `break` from the loop, no need to continue searching, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct i have a vector of strings and i will populate another vector with strings and i have to check that the 1st vector **test** contains those strings from **test1** @LuchianGrigore

Comment: @ShamariCampbell ok, then this should do it.

Comment: oh yeah i mean to put test1 sorry @LuchianGrigore

Comment: However if i put an else and a `break` inside the `else` it would not work as it also goes into `else` if the `strings` are present @LuchianGrigore

Comment: @ShamariCampbell you also need `end` instead of `begin`. It will only go in `else` if the string is found in the vector. Otherwise, it will break from the loop. If you break in the `if`, it won't go into `else`.

Comment: oh ok so i now have the `break` in the `if block` and a `print statement` in the `else block` so if one of the `strings` are not found it wll `break` ok i shall try this @LuchianGrigore

Answer (score 1):

If you can sort the two vectors, you can use `std::includes`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add a solution which doesn't include an explicit for, and supposing that:

- There are no repeated items in test1.
- You are looking for exactly the same string to be contained in test.

  ```
  #include <vector>
  #include <string>
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  struct StringFoundCounter 
  {
      StringFoundCounter(const vector<string>& haystack) 
          : sum(0), haystack(haystack) { }

      void operator()(string needle) {
          if (find(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), needle) != haystack.end())
              sum++;
      }

      int get_sum() const  { return sum; }

  private:
      int sum;
      const vector<string>& haystack;
  };

  int main()
  {
      std::vector<std::string> test;
      test.push_back("YES");
      test.push_back("YES");
      test.push_back("NO");
      test.push_back("NO");

      std::vector<std::string> test1;
      test1.push_back("YES");
      test1.push_back("NO");
      test1.push_back("CR");

      StringFoundCounter sfc = 
          for_each(test1.begin(), test1.end(), StringFoundCounter(test));

      if (test1.size() == sfc.get_sum())
          cout << "All elements found" << endl;
      else
          cout << "Some or all elements not found" << endl;
  }
  ```

  ~

Answer (score 0):

I also needed something similar, so wrote a few lines which work perfectly fine for me.

```
    // allCollectableItems is a vector<string> containing all strings to be searched
    // itemsCollected is a vector<string> in which allCollectableItems are to be looked for

    bool allItemsFound = true;
    
                    for (string item : allCollectableItems)
                    {
                        if (std::find(itemsCollected.begin(), itemsCollected.end(), item) == itemsCollected.end())
                        {
                            allItemsFound = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

// allItemsFound will be the required value
```